# model is not updated after manual change attribute value ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I trying use editor with custom tags
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg2kg.png)
this tags has attributes. When I change value in html model dont know about it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBqxI.png)
After change attribute value I havent any fire event.

Additionally
Attribute changing in external component angular, but html changed inside editor.

I try several variants with  `attributeToAttribute`  but not result.
Any ideas, please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you provide your code and error message directly in the question by copy / pasting / formating it instead of giving an external link ? It will help other to better understand your question and help you in the most efficient way. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask